# How to shrink home partition on a running OS (Ubuntu Linux)?

Tags: gparted, unmount

[image: GParted screenshot with partitions and error message "Could not unmount"]

I want to reduce the size of the `/home` partition, so I need to unmount it. How can I do it using GParted?

What type of file system is better for accessing both Windows and Linux?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu. Please use one question at a time. Your second question is primarily opinion based, and likely to be closed if asked as a separate question.

Comment: I think you would have to enable root then login as root... if you are logged in as a user your home folder will always be in use. or you can boot from live USB and use gparted there maybe?

Comment: You can access NTFS on Ubuntu, just run: `sudo apt install ntfs-3g`

Comment: what will be the better option using ntfs or fat32

Comment: Obvious, but you cannot use NTFS or Fat32 for /home. Use  Live USB to reduce /home. P.S. I never use extended for /home or swap, so I have never reduced them with Live USB. ExFAT is dangerous with Linux! If you intentionally or accidentally do a _filesystem check_, you could lose all your data, I have done it once...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Basically, **you cannot modify the structure of a mounted partition** (which you are using).

### Home, boot, data partition

So a `home` partition can typically be unmounted using another user logged in, umount it and modify its structure.

### Slash or extended partition when slash mounted on

You have to do this from a live UFD/DVD as you cannot unmount a Linux system partition on an hdd/ssd while it is directly or potentially in use.

As far as file systems are concerned, with Windows use NTFS and with Ubuntu system devices, stay with ext4. If you plan to stay with Windows keep data files on an NTFS system or use [extufsd](http://www.ext2fsd.com/) for example.

Comment: I have another question, can I increase the size of "extended partition"? and how?

Comment: @Md.Mony: if it's another question, make it another question ;)

Answer (score -1):

if you want to reduce home partition size means it definitely affects the whole working  Linux operating system. while Linux machine is running it is not possible to edit the home partition. it can be done by using bootable Linux USB/cd (any Linux os, ex Ubuntu, Kali Linux) and gparted is installed on it. in this way also you may destroy your running Ubuntu os. but I tried this it workes for me. Hope that this s work for you also.

Comment: Reducing the Home partition can't damage the Ubuntu installation if there really is a home partition, and a separate OS partition. Even if there is only one partition, I don't see how shrinking it will cause damage, especially if it is just about 10% full, as the picture shows.

Comment: ok I solve it by using a live CD. Thank you so much.

Answer (score -2):

1. Log in as another user; typically `Ctrl+alt+F1` username -> enter -> pwd ([Instructions to create another](https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/user-management.html.en#adding-deleting-users) if you don't have one yet; that other user must be added to the group sudoer)
2. Shutdown graphical interface `sudo service sddm stop`
3. Unmount home `sudo umount /home`
4. `resize2fs /dev/sda6 6000M` or the size you want
5. Remount all partitions defined into /etc/fstab which include /home `sudo mount -a`
6. Restart you graphical interface  `sudo service sddm start`

Comment: Logging in as another user will not solve the problem, unless the user is `root`. All other users have their **Home** folder under `/home/user1`, `/home/user2` etc. The `/home` partition is mounted and locked whether `user1` is logged in or `user2` is logged in. Create another user, `user3` and she gets `/home/user3` as her home. So, you cannot unmount `/home` unless you enable `root` login or boot from another drive, such as a Live USB or DVD.

Comment: @user68186 Users without home directory are possible, so in theory this method should work.

Comment: @SaurabhSingh though it is possible to create an user without a home directory, it is not the default behavior. More importantly this answer does not explain that one needs to create an user without associating the user with the corresponding home directory. Even more importantly the answer does not describe how to create such an user. To be specific, it is not sufficient to have an existing user and adding her to the `sudoer` group. The answer as it stands should not work.